# Visual Studio C# 2010 Express code editor and "-" characters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express

Here's what my IDE looks like:

------------switch (LastKnownFilter)
------------{
----------------case "MatchGroupNets":
--------------------SelectedList = lvMatchGroupNets;
--------------------break;
----------------case "MatchGroupComps":
--------------------SelectedList = lvMatchGroupComps;
--------------------break;
----------------case "Net":
-------------------SelectedList = lvNets;

How can I get rid of these `-` characters? I didn't change any settings. I just opened my Visual Studio Express and saw these in all of my code files. I don't like it. How can I get rid of these "-" characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toggle it on/off with: *Edit* > *Advanced* > *View white space*.

The hotkey is usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Im using VSExpress :D theres no Advanced on my Edit menu :/  

EDIT: But the hotkey worked.. Thanks :D